# UIImage Pixel rotation

Tags: iphone, image-processing

I'm looking for a snippet of code that will demonstrate UIImage Pixel rotation. all the example I found so far was not very clear. Basically I want to give my user the options to rotate his image after he took a picture with the camera.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hard to parse "UIImage" in sans-serif.  u capital-i image?  u lower-L image?  I vote for serifed fonts everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres some great categories which show the transforms you can apply to UIImage available here 
http://www.platinumball.net/blog/2010/01/31/iphone-uiimage-rotation-and-scaling/

Answer (score 1):

You can consider a [`CGAffineTransform`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html) that applies a rotation to the [`UIImageView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), considering that a UIImageView is a subclass of [`UIView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)